# What does operator float*() do?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, overloading, conversion-operator

I have been looking through source code trying to learn more about C++ and I came across some code that looked confusing. I haven't been able to figure out its use by playing around with it.

Please can someone explain what the operator float *() does and how it is used?

```
class Vector
{
public:
    float x,y,z;
```

`Vector() : x(0), y(0), z(0){
    }

    Vector( float x, float y, float z ) : x(x), y(y), z(z){
    }

    operator float*(){
        return &x;
    }

    operator const float *(){
        return &x;
    }`

I have searched StackOverflow and it looks like it is a conversion operator but I am still unsure what it actually does and why it is useful.

Kind regards,

Comment: Neither answer so far is explaining why it is conversion to `float*` not `float`. The non-const could be a deliberate desire to break encapsulation, but why would anyone ever write a `const float *` conversion??  ---> Aha, just seen Matt's comment about the point being to assume x,y,z are contiguous in memory. OK, dubious design, but I get it now :-)

Comment: @Darren I won’t attempt to explain it because I can’t. It’s simply a bad idea. I am *suspecting* that the original author wanted to expose an array-like interface for the vector but this is a bad idea for the reasons mentioned in the comments below my answer (and more).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`operator type_name` declares an *implicit conversion* operator. In other words, this function is called when you are attempting to (implicitly) convert an object of your type to `float*` – for instance in an assignment:

```
Vector x(1, 2, 3);
float* f = x;
assert(*f == 1);
```

Needless to say, this particular conversion is quite terrible because its effect is pretty unintuitive and easily results in impossible to find bugs. Implicit conversions should generally be handled with care since they hide potentially confusing semantics. But they can be used well with types which are supposed to be used interchangeably, and where a conversion doesn’t hurt.

For instance, consider the case where you write your own `integer` and `complex` classes. A conversion from `integer` to `complex` is harmless, since every integer is a complex number (but *not* vice-versa). So having an implicit conversion `integer` → `complex` is safe.

Comment: seconding it being terrible.

Comment: Would a safer alternative be:  float &operator[]( int n ){ return (&x)[n]; }

Comment: @MattMcNabb Assuming that's really the entire definition of the class (or at least that it has no virtual members and no base classes), then they *are* in fact guaranteed to be contiguous and in the order they're declared, as the thing is a standard-layout struct.

Comment: @Matt McNabb The order of data members is guaranteed.

Comment: @Angew and Vlad - you're quite right; although this class is non-POD, it is still *standard-layout* which is specified by `[class]#7`

Comment: @NoOdle Yes, that would indeed be a safer way. However, that has its own shortcomings since it doesn’t offer the usual container interface. A “proper” solution would provide all these. An easier solution would implement the vector in terms of a `std::array`, and then provide an (implicit or explicit) conversion to `std::array&`.

Answer (score 7):

As it was said it is a conversion operator that converts an object of type `Vector` to an object of type `float *`. This conversion operator can be called implicitly because it has no function specifier `explicit`.

I think that the idea of introducing this operator was to access data members x, y, z as an array of floats.  In this case you could apply some standard algorithms to an object of the class converting it to an array of floats.

Take into account that the second overloaded operator-function shall have qualifier const.

Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


class Vector
{
public:
    float x,y,z;



    Vector() : x(0), y(0), z(0){
    }

    Vector( float x, float y, float z ) : x(x), y(y), z(z){
    }

    operator float*(){
        return &x;
    }

    operator const float *() const {
        return &x;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Vector v( 1, 3, 2 );
    auto max = std::max_element( v + 0, v + 3 );
    std::cout << *max << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 3.

Take into account that according to the C++ Standard

> 13 Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access
>   control (Clause 11) are allocated so that **later members have higher
>   addresses within a class object**

So the order of the data members of the class is defined.

Answer (score 3):

It's a conversion operator allowing the class to be used with APIs that want a `float*`.You have two different versions because one will convert the class to a `const float*` and the other to a non-`const`. The non-const conversion operator breaks your class's encapsulation though.

Usefulness: Well it can be very handy when, as I mentioned, you want to work with a library that expects a certain type. It can also be useful when there is a natural conversion between two types.

Comment: @Angew Thanks for the _pointer_  :)  Obviously I knew that as I pointed out the broken encapsulation, but I was unclear in my answer. I have updated it.